# how to read out (<c:out value=... >) a taglib attribute in the JSP

Tags: jsp, attributes, taglib

I just want to read out the attributes ( in the .tld) that I've set in the JSP before. I just don't know how to ouput them . After trying the suggestions in the article of [How to use <c:out value=...> taglib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028922/how-to-use-cout-value-taglib) I get an empty value output. So the variable (e. g. "instanzVar1") seems to be somehow out of scope.

**Here my .java:**

```
public class BirolName extends SimpleTagSupport implements SimpleTag {
String instanzVar1;
Boolean instanzVar2;
int instanzVar3;    

@Override
public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
    //Zum Schreiben in die JSP "JSPWriter"
    JspWriter outputJSP = getJspContext().getOut();
    outputJSP.println("Birol was here :-) (Taglib von Java -nach-> JSP hat funktionniert!)");
    outputJSP.println("Die eingegebenen Paramter über die JSP waren:");
    outputJSP.println("<br /><b>");
    outputJSP.println("Paramter 1:"+instanzVar1);
    outputJSP.println("<br />");
    outputJSP.println("Paramter 2:"+instanzVar2);
    outputJSP.println("<br />");
    outputJSP.println("Paramter 3:"+instanzVar3);
    outputJSP.println("</b><br />");
}

public String getInstanzVar1() {
    return instanzVar1;
}


public void setInstanzVar1(String instanzVar1) {
    this.instanzVar1 = instanzVar1;
}
......
}
```

**my .tld:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd">
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>st</short-name>
    <tag>
        <name>birolNameTag</name>
        <tag-class>st.BirolName</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
        <attribute>
            <name>instanzVar1</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>instanzVar2</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>instanzVar3</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

**And at least the .jsp:**

```
   <!-- Einbindung des Taglibs -->
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/st.tld" prefix="st"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<p>
    Aufruf der Taglib mit "taglibPrefix:NameDesTag"
    <br /> <st:birolNameTag instanzVar1="BirolString" instanzVar2="true" instanzVar3="1"/>
    <br /><br />

    <jsp:useBean id="a" class="st.BirolName"/>
    Ausgabe des Paramters: <c:out value = "${a.instanzVar1}" />
</p>
```

The solution is most likely quite simple. Still I didn't really got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution.
Simply used in the .java tag class this code:

```
JspContext pcontext = getJspContext();    
pcontext.setAttribute("myAttribute", this.instanzVar1.concat(this.instanzVar1), Util.getScope("request"));
```

The "**setAttribute()**" offers me to save a value in a attribute (here: "myAttribute"). 
Description:
In my case, I set the attributes in the JSP by using my taglib attributes. Then I could set them in my .java, simply by putting them in as the 2nd paramter in the setAttribute (here: "**this.instanzVar1.concat(this.instanzVar1**"). Now I had what I wanted, because this new attribute "myAttribute" that was set in .java could be called in the JSP with ${myAttribute}.

Answer (score 0):

WHat you're doing makes no sense. You should see a JSP tag as a Java method, taking arguments. Once the method has been called, you can't get a handle on the method and ask it what the arguments were the last tie it was called.

The container will have a pool of `BirolName` instance, and will use them on several pages, in several threads.

And when you do

```
<jsp:useBean id="a" class="st.BirolName"/>,
```

it's equivalent to doing

```
st.BirolName a = new st.BirolName();
```

So you can't expect finding the arguments to the tag you used before from this new instance of the tag class.

When you pass a value to the instanzVar1 attribute of the tag, you're not setting any JSP attribute. You're just passing an argument to your tag. To set an page scope attribute, you must use the `c:set` tag:

```
<c:set var="someAttribute" value="someValue"/>
${someAttribute} <%-- prints someValue --%>
```

Comment: True, but I can't see the changes JSP after making them in the .java Klasse, after changing it. E.g. with this code in die BirolName.java: this.instanzVar1 = this.instanzVar1.concat(this.instanzVar1);

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java. `this.instanzVar1.concat(this.instanzVar1)` doesn't modify `this.instanzVar1`. It creates a new String containing the concatenation.

Comment: Thanks, I've found a suitable solution.